# Terminal history

Tags: command-line

I looking for the terminal history. Not only the command history that is showed by typing `history` but terminal processes within a command. That is, I want to record the output displayed by the commands in the terminal.

For example, One wanna install a package and types `sudo apt-get install xxxx` then is when terminal is telling you what is doing, it asks for confirmation, for installing additional packages, etc. –

Comment: What do you mean by “terminal processes within a command”?

Comment: @Gilles What terminal tells that is doing when something is commanded

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you mean the output from a command? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Gilles For example, One wanna install a package and types `sudo apt-get install xxxx` then is when terminal is telling you what is doing, it asks for confirmation, for installing aditional packages, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29#Text_.28CLI.29_shells) keeps a history of the commands that you type, that's what the `history` command gives you. There is no automatic history of the output from the commands that you run in the terminal. Once you close the terminal, the output is lost unless you saved it somewhere.

You can save a complete transcript of a terminal session by running the [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/script.1.html) command. If you run the command `script`, you get a new shell prompt; all the commands that you type from that point, as well as their output, are entered in the log. The log file is closed when you exit the `script` subsession (which returns you to the parent shell — entering `exit` or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> a second time exits the parent shell).

The default history file name is `typescript` (in the current directory). If there is already a file by that name, it is overwritten. You can specify a different file name by passing it as an argument to `script`, e.g. `script hello.txt`.

If you want to keep the history after closing a terminal, but don't mind losing the history when you switch off your computer, you can run [screen](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/screen) or [tmux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tmux).

Answer (score 0):

Please see `man history` for more details:

**DESCRIPTION**

> Many programs read input from the user a line at a time.  The GNU History  library  is able to keep track of those lines, associate arbitrary data with each line, and utilize information from previous lines in composing new ones.

**HISTORY EXPANSION**

> The history library supports a history expansion feature that is identical to the history expansion in bash.  This section describes what  syntax features are available.
>
> History  expansions introduce words from the history list into the input stream, making it easy to repeat commands, insert  the  arguments  to  a previous  command into the current input line, or fix errors in previous commands quickly.
>
> History expansion is usually performed immediately after a complete line is  read.  It takes place in two parts.  The first is to determine which line from the history list to use during substitution.  The second is to select  portions  of  that line for inclusion into the current one.  The line selected from the history is the event, and the  portions  of  that line  that are acted upon are words.  Various modifiers are available to manipulate the selected words.  The line is broken  into  words  in  the same fashion as bash does when reading input, so that several words that would otherwise be separated are considered one word when surrounded  by quotes  (see  the  description  of  history_tokenize()  below).  History expansions are introduced by the appearance  of  the  history  expansion character,  which is ! by default.  Only backslash () and single quotes can quote the history expansion character.
>
> Event Designators:
>
> An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in  the  history list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative to the current position in the history list.

---

Now, to answer your question! Here are the directories, where your bash-history is saved. And YES, there is the command history, that you can access in terminal with <kbd>⇥</kbd>-key located:

> ```
> ~/.bash_history    
> /root/.bash_history
> ```

You can use `cat ~/.bash_history`, to see the listing/content of previous used commands. You can also open the ".bash_history", with `gnome-open ~/.bash_history`, in order to edit the list, or `rm ~/.bash_history`, to [rm=remove] the history (".bash_history" will be autogenerated, so it is save to delete it).

[image: history-command-preview]